# Query to get totals in a row based on more than 1 column

Tags: sql

Given this table layout

```
primary_status | submitted_total_A | total_paid_A | secondary_status | submitted_total_B | total_paid_B
O              | 100.00            | 0            | C                | 250.00            | 250.00
C              | 150.00            | 150.00       | N                | 0.00                                                                            |  0.00
C              | 300.00            | 0            | O                | 50.00             | 25.00
O              | 400.00            | 50.00        | O                | 500.00            | 100.00
```

I'm trying to get the sum of submitted_total_A - total_paid_A (when primary_status = 'O') + submitted_total_B - total_paid_B (when secondary_status = 'O').  So basically, when either status column contains 'O', the related 'A' and 'B' columns get included in the calculation of a new column "row_total".

The expected results would be:

*Row 1 "row_total" would be 100.00 (only include the "A" columns difference)

*Row 2 "row_total" would be 0.00 (neither status column contained an 'O')

*Row 3 "row_total" would be 25.00 (only include the "B" columns difference)

*Row 4 "row_total" would be 750.00 (include both "A" and "B" columns difference)

This is the query I have but I know the value is wrong because the "OR" will select both the "A" and "B" when either status is 'O':

```
SELECT ( submitted_total_a - total_paid_a + submitted_total_b - total_paid_b ) 
       AS 
       'row_total' 
FROM   table_1 
WHERE  primary_status = 'O' 
        OR secondary_status = 'O';
```

Comment: Please share the query that you've tried

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ( CASE 
           WHEN primary_status = 'O' THEN ( submitted_total_a - total_paid_a ) 
           ELSE 0 
         END ) + 
       ( CASE 
           WHEN secondary_status = 'O' THEN ( submitted_total_b - total_paid_b ) 
           ELSE 0 
         END ) row_total 
FROM   table
```

simple use of `CASE WHEN`, it works like a block of `[if, else]` conditions, equivalent of a `switch/case` in PHP for example